# must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a chat application and facing a problem while creating a group (Recycler View's List item) and to inflate it over the fragment  container.

Actually, two kind of views are being inflated. One is the root View that will be inflated in a fragment container and second is inflated as another custom layout for Dialog ask for input group name.

FAB is implemented as a click event to launch Dialog to input channel name. First time when i click a FAB, dialog appears ask for channel name to create group. After passing, an input group is created and Channel/Group (Recycler View's List item) is created and inflated over the container. But second time when I click on FAB, to repeat the process, to create another group/channel, the app crashes and error is encountered on logcat.

"The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first".
  I don't have too much knowledge about fragments and don't know what does that error means. Please help to resolve this error.

Thanks

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_open_channel_list, container, false);

    CFAlertDialogue_footerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cfalertdialog_footer_view_open_channel, null);
    editText_ChannelName = CFAlertDialogue_footerView.findViewById(R.id.textInputEditText_channelName);

    setRetainInstance(true);

    mRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_openChannelList);
    channelListAdapter = new openChannelListAdapter(getContext());

    refreshLayout = rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_open_channel_list);
    refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            refreshChannelList(CHANNEL_LIST_LIMIT);
        }
    });

    actionButton = rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab_addOpenChannel);
    actionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CFAlertDialog.Builder dialog = new CFAlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                    .setDialogStyle(CFAlertDialog.CFAlertStyle.ALERT)
                    .setTitle("Create Open Channel")
                    .setTextGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL)
                    .setCornerRadius(5)
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setFooterView(CFAlertDialogue_footerView)
                    .addButton("Cancel", Color.parseColor("#000000"), Color.parseColor("#f8f8ff"),
                            CFAlertDialog.CFAlertActionStyle.NEGATIVE, CFAlertDialog.CFAlertActionAlignment.JUSTIFIED,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            })
                    .addButton("Create", Color.parseColor("#000000"), Color.parseColor("#8b3a3a"),
                            CFAlertDialog.CFAlertActionStyle.POSITIVE, CFAlertDialog.CFAlertActionAlignment.JUSTIFIED,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                    OpenChannel.createChannelWithOperatorUserIds(editText_ChannelName.getText().toString(),
                                            null, null, null, null, new OpenChannel.OpenChannelCreateHandler() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onResult(OpenChannel openChannel, SendBirdException e) {

                                                    if ( e != null){
                                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error Creating Channel: "+e.getCode()+" "
                                                                +e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        return;
                                                    }

                                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                                    refreshChannelList(CHANNEL_LIST_LIMIT);
                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });

    setUpRecyclerViewAndAdapter();

    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: somewhere you are creating a dynamic view and you have added to view but forgot to remove it.

Comment: but where is the problem, which statement ? please help me to sort out. I don't know where i'm committing mistake because of low knowledge about fragments.

Comment: Actually 3 views are being created rootView, CFAlertDialog_footerView and dialog. And one thing i need to know why we need to remove a view?

Comment: Your are adding view in recyclerview?

Comment: post your logcat and also highlight the line of code where the error is occurring .

Comment: yup, in recycler view . .

Comment: post you `recyclerView` code

Comment: error is occurring at "dialog.show"

Comment: I'm waiting for your answer #farhana

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
final AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            b.setView(layout);
            b.show();
```

to

```
final AlertDialog.Builder b = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
b.setView(layout);
final AlertDialog alertDialog = b.show();
```

Try to change something like this

Comment: do you have a github profile? I want to share my project so that you will experience my problem at runtime. I will be really thankful to you !

Comment: I think there is a network issue sorry for delay. This is my repository link https://github.com/Adnan-Javed/ChatFat.git, clone it and please tell me where am i committing a logical error! And i wanna stay actively engaged with you on that if you don't mind. (Any Social Media Profile facebook, whatsapp etc  ?)